# Google maps custom button with standard style

Tags: javascript, google-maps, button, google-maps-api-3, styles

Is there any way to add custom button to the Google Maps using their latest api, so that it will use the same style as other standard buttons? I'd be thankful for a sample code demonstrating the solution.

Comment: What are the buttons that you want it to look like?  I would just use the developer tools in IE or Chrome and select the button you want via click and grab the css, and apply to your button

Comment: @UserSmith: The standard ones: http://i.imgur.com/0dF6hCL.png. I can't just hardcode the styles as it won't adjust when they update the API. And it's a messy solution.

Comment: I agree it is a quick and dirty solution.  If you knew the id or class associated with the button you want to mock you could essentially steal the css via jquery from that object and apply it to your button, but you would probably receive a bunch of css that you don't want.  I am not sure of a solution that is going to keep you up to date for their next api version because I  don't know what the new api verison will contain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no default class that you can apply or anything else. You'll have to follow up development and change your styling when Google Maps changes it.

For the current version:

MarkUp

```
<div class="gmnoprint custom-control-container">
    <div class="gm-style-mtc">
        <div class="custom-control" title="Click to set the map to Home">Home</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.custom-control-container {
    margin: 5px;
}
.custom-control {
    cursor: pointer;
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 1px 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px;
    min-width: 28px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.custom-control:hover {
    font-weight: 900 !important;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/pvA93/) that does exactly this. Some of the style attributes still get applied directly by maps. What's not getting applied is `cursor: pointer;` and some styles might need `!important` as suffix so it doesn't get overridden by maps.

Keep in mind that you can already add a visual refresh (sneak preview for the new maps styles) with

```
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
```

You might have to refresh when this gets the default.