# Customize default mapType button in Google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, arcgis

I am trying to customize the default mapType button in Google API. What I am trying to do is trying to increase the height for the box of mapType and here is the code:

```
function initLeftMap(initialMapTypeId, planClicked) {
var initialMap_url;
var initialMap_name;
var initialMap_svc = new gmaps.ags.MapService(initialMap_url);
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(initialMap_svc, 'load', function () {
    try {
        if (initialMapTypeId == "onemap") {
            initialMap_svc.spatialReference.wkid = 3414;  // impt! or else
            // overlays
            // can't show on
            // onemap

        }

        var initialMap_tileLayer = new gmaps.ags.TileLayer(initialMap_svc);
        var initialMap_agsType = new gmaps.ags.MapType([initialMap_tileLayer], {
            name: initialMap_name
        });
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 11,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.347074, 103.81382),
            mapTypeId: initialMapTypeId, // google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [initialMapTypeId,
                                google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                                google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID],
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            },
            streetViewControl: true,
            scaleControl: true
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        map.mapTypes.set(initialMapTypeId, initialMap_agsType);

                    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', function (e) {
            toggleBaseMapLegend();
        });

        initRightMap(initialMapTypeId, initialMap_agsType, planClicked);
        //load the last viewed extent
        loadLastState();

        // init after map is created
        initBuffer(map);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);

    }
});
}
```

I wonder is there any way to style it by using css under the style tag? Or is there any better way to customize it by increasing the height of the box only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, yes. It's not particularly *easy*, since Google don't give you many hooks to nail down that `div` and it's not a documented feature so they could change it whenever they want.

Looking at the page source, your best bet is to use the `gm-style-mtc` class to target the base `div` of the map selector:

```
<div class="gmnoprint gm-style-mtc" style="margin: 5px; z-index: 0; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; text-align: left; width: 200px; right: 0px; top: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 35, 0);">
```

So your CSS becomes:

```
<style>
     .gm-style-mtc > div:first-child {
         width: 150px;
         height: 60px;
         ...and so on
     }
</style>
```

You can target the children (the individual options in the dropdown, etc) by using some combination of `.gm-style-mtc > div`, `gm-style-mtc > div > div` etc. Endless fun to be had with [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033343/google-maps-custom-button-with-standard-style) might be useful to you as well.

Comment: I think you might need to specify the child selector because by viewing the page source, its the child div that set the height. Also you might need !important for the css property cause it works for me.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct - the `:first-child` pseudo-selector is also useful, otherwise it tries to match the actual dropdown menu as well (depending on what you're actually trying to do....). Updated my answer. Obviously this is all fragile, and depends on Google not changing the way that dropdown is constructed in future versions of the API.